# Returning "Text" in a cell based on colour format of another cell

Tags: if-statement, conditional-formatting

In my example, cells, any cells contain numeric data and **if that data is unique** within a selected range of cells, then it formats its host cell, using conditional formatting with say, a red fill. In another cell I want to return the text "YES" whenever the precedent is formatted as described. I have read elsewhere that the best way to do these sorts of things is to mimic the underlying function???? of the precedent cell, but I cannot think of a way to do this with the criteria of it being - unique.
I only have a basic knowledge of excel so please excuse me if this comes across as a bit muddled.
Can this be done?

I have generally fiddled around but did not achieve the outcome sought.